# echo 4G > memory.max: memory.max always 0

Tags: linux, cgroups

I'm trying to set a memory limit with cgroup2 with this command:

```
echo 4G > memory.max
```

This works fine on my laptop, but on my server `cat memory.max` always returns `0`. No matter what I write to it (even writing `max` doesn't work), it is always `0`

What is happening here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the trailing newline when using echo, which is interpreted as a `0`.

e.g.:

```
$ cat memory.max 
max
$ echo 4G > memory.max 
$ cat memory.max 
0
$ echo -n 4G > memory.max 
$ cat memory.max 
4294967296
$ echo max > memory.max 
$ cat memory.max 
0
$ echo -n max > memory.max 
$ cat memory.max 
max
```

Normally it should work with a newline, but it depends on which **libc** version you are using.

e.g. On a system with glibc `strace echo 4G` returns this:

```
...
write(1, "4G\n", 34G
)                     = 3
...
```

However, if you use musl-libc you get this instead:

```
...
writev(1, [{iov_base="4G", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 24G
) = 3
...
```